# Xamarin.Forms when click on ListView ViewCell background color changed to orange , but not initialized to a color

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This is my code

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewClient"  ItemsSource="{Binding Client}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >


                        <Grid  Margin="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <BoxView  Grid.Column="0" Color="#84DCC6"/>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="20, 10">

                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="Name:" FontSize="16" />
                                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Adress:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Adress}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Place:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Place}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke" >
                                    <Grid >

                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="Mobile:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                    <Label  FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Mobile}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Call" Clicked="PovikajPartnerClicked" BackgroundColor="#84DCC6"></Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="Е-mail:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding EMAIL}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="LAW:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding LAW}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                                <Frame BorderColor="WhiteSmoke
                                       ">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="SECNUM:"  FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding SECNUM}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I dont know from where get that orange background color when i tap on the listview. From the code you can see that i dont have choosed samo backgroud color . Is there a default tap event to make the color orange? I tried everything but cant find is there anyplace i forgot to add a color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this may be a bit late, but I hope it will help someone, Just go your styles.xml file under AppName.Android/Resources/values and inside your Main Theme add the following:

```
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the default selection colour of your ListView that comes from the theme of your App that Xamarin by default has set in the template to solve it just add the following to your ListView

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None" ..../>
```

Comment: if i want without SelectionMode="None" where should i change the orange backgroud color?

Comment: You will know to set `SelectedItem` to null but it will still show the orange colour, For it to not show at all you will have to change the `MainTheme` in your `Styles.xml`, May I know why do you not want to do it through this property?

Comment: when i click on cell its showing orange .i want to be transparent or white

Comment: its not suitable for my design\

Comment: Yeah so set selectionMode to none and it will select the item but not show on ui

Comment: but i cant select an item

Comment: When you say you can't select an item what do you mean? You want your item to have a selected color?

Comment: I maked new post and make with custom render

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but this solution I found on Grepper might be helpful. It is simple and is unique for each content page.
You can alter the background color of the current cell and the previous cell using the ViewCell Tapped event.

XAML:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped" >
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="DarkGoldenrod" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In your code add:

```
ViewCell lastCell;
private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (lastCell != null)
        lastCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    var viewCell = (ViewCell)sender;
    if (viewCell.View != null)
    {
        viewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
        lastCell = viewCell;
    }
}
```